# In framework 7 id and attributes replicate on another page

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

This is a cordova android app, i am using framework7, I have created a data-page with name "shop" and id and i am accessing that data-page name through id. I have created another page with different data-page name. I have set an alert to get the data-page name. Whenever i go to other page from "shop" page i get on alert data-page name "shop" though other pages have different data-page name. Please help me solving this.

//Code to exit with confirmation

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", ready, false);

function devReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {
    var page = $('#helloid').attr('data-page');
    alert("back button click from " + page);
    if (page == 'shop') {
        exitAppPopup();
    } else {
        history.back();
    };
});
};

function exitAppPopup() {
navigator.notification.confirm(
    "Do you really want to close this app?",
    function(buttonIndex) {
        ConfirmExit(buttonIndex);
    },
    "Confirmation",
    "Yes,No"
);
```

};

```
function ConfirmExit(stat) {
//alert("Inside ConfirmExit");
if (stat == "1") {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
} else {
    return;web
};
};
```

// page1: home.html

```
<div data-page="shop" class="page navbar-fixed" id="helloid">
    <div class="navbar">

    </div>
</div>
```

//Page2: With different data-page name std.html

```
<div data-page="inch" class="page navbar-fixed">
<div class="navbar ">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `var page = $('#helloid').attr('data-page');` due to this variable.Everytime when you click on backbutton,your code will fetch **data-page** attribute of **helloid** id.which will remain same throughout your whole system.

Comment: solved this by using different logic, thanks for your help.